# how to wrap a c# dll to use in qt c++?

Tags: c#, qt, dll

I have a C# dll which I want to use in a Qt C++ application. How can I do this work.
I searched the Internet and found that I need to do a Wrapping method, but I don't know how to do this.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question [CallC#FromC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643856/c-sharp-form-application-in-c-dll/41646218#41646218), but there are some things you need to known before you continue. All the C++ code including the QT framework has been compiled with VC++, and therefore only `.lib` and `.dll` binaries exist. You can build the QT binaries by using [MicrosoftVCPackages](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) or you can use my [QTFrameworkBuild](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-mLEsywAIXBUUc3ZDZYdEdqUXc). All you need to do is follow the same instructions as the similar question [CallC#FromC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643856/c-sharp-form-application-in-c-dll/41646218#41646218).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that method.